# Kotlin launch vs launch(Dispatchers.Default)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I was testing out how blocking code and coroutines interact for my own understanding. Obviously, we should use non-blocking but I wanted to understand what would happen if there was some blocking code in there.

If I run the following:

```
fun main() {
    println("Start: ${Thread.currentThread()}")
    runBlocking {
        println("Run Blocking : ${Thread.currentThread()}")
        launch(Dispatchers.D) { // Immediately scheduled for execution
            println("Inside launch: ${Thread.currentThread()}")
        }
        Thread.sleep(10000)
        println("Going to do some other stuff now")
    }
    println("Out of runBlocking")

}
```

everything runs in the same coroutine and `Inside launch:` doesn't appear until the `Thread.sleep` has completed. I assume this is because it is blocking, so no suspending, or use of another coroutine can take place.

If I pass `Dispatchers.Default` to `launch` (I thought launch used `Dispatchers.Default` by default, if you didn't specify one?), the launch block runs in a separate coroutine and starts immediately.

So, why does `launch(Dispatchers.Default)` allow the second coroutine to start and why doesn't just `launch` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought launch used Dispatchers.Default by default, if you didn't specify one

This is where you're mistaken. Here is the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html):

> The coroutine context is inherited from a CoroutineScope. Additional context elements can be specified with context argument. If the context does not have any dispatcher nor any other ContinuationInterceptor, then Dispatchers.Default is used.

This means that if you don't pass a dispatcher to `launch`, it will default to the dispatcher present in the context of the `CoroutineScope` in which you started that `launch`. If the coroutine context doesn't have a dispatcher, *then* `launch` will use `Dispatchers.Default`.

So in your case, a parameterless `launch` inherits the context and thus the dispatcher provided by `runBlocking`, which is a single-threaded dispatcher running on the thread that it blocks (the main thread here).

> why does `launch(Dispatchers.Default)` allow the second coroutine to start and why doesn't just `launch` ?

This is because, as we've just seen, these 2 cases don't involve the same threads. With `launch(Dispatchers.Default)`, the launched coroutine runs on a separate thread pool and can run in parallel of the main one. However, with the parameterless `launch`, the second coroutine runs on the same thread as the rest of the code, because it runs in the single-threaded dispatcher of `runBlocking`, which is backed by the main thread.

The last piece of the puzzle is that `Thread.sleep` is *blocking* (as you said), unlike `delay` which is the suspend equivalent from the coroutines library. When there is only one thread involved (in the case of the parameterless `launch`), running the last `Thread.sleep` blocks the main thread and never gives a chance to the other coroutine to run. You would need something to suspend execution, for instance `delay()`.

Comment: How do we know that the dispatcher of `runBlocking` is single-threaded? Could you link to a documentation source which states this?

Comment: Found it: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#unconfined-vs-confined-dispatcher

Comment: Actually it's even clearer in the doc if the `runBlocking` function (in the JVM tab, not the common) https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html: *The default CoroutineDispatcher for this builder is an internal implementation of event loop that processes continuations in this blocked thread until the completion of this coroutine*